# How to turn off all RAISE NOTICE on production server?

Tags: postgresql, logs, plpgsql

I put a lot of RAISE NOTICE in functions for debugging purpose. I think this will affect performance, so they should be removed on production environment. Is there any way to opt-out those logging/assertion functions only under specific conditions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could wrap them in an `IF` clause that tests a custom configuration variable. This will work but it's a bit verbose and each statement in PL/PgSQL has a cost.

I suspect you'll be better off lowering the log level in the `RAISE` messages so you log on a level like `DEBUG` that isn't captured by `log_min_messages` by default. That way you can just turn it on by changing `client_min_messages` or `log_min_messages`.

See the expanded form of the `RAISE` statement, eg:

```
RAISE DEBUG USING MESSAGE = 'TheMessage';
```

See [the documentation for the `RAISE` statement](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-errors-and-messages.html).

Alternately, you can leave your messages at `RAISE NOTICE` and increase the log level, but that may hide other information you'll want to see in the logs. Better to log with a lower priority initially.

So long as the notices aren't doing lots of expensive string formatting or being called huge numbers of times I suspect you won't have too much trouble with their performance impact while logging to file/client is suppressed by log levels.